# Active Nodes in Subnet (SendARP)

Tags: windows, network-programming, arp, iocp

All,

I am trying to find active nodes in my Subnet. For that I am sending ARP to all nodes in subnet. Is this the right way to do this ?  If this is the right way, Is there any good way to handle this using IOCompletion Port or similar threading concepts?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about IOCompletion, but yes this is an acceptable way to find all nodes on the subnet. The popular network scanner nmap does exactly this when you scan a network (if you have privileges to create ARP packets at least), sends ARP requests for all the IP addresses and checks if it gets unique MAC address replies (if not unique, it could be proxy ARP through a router or some sort of network utility to make scanning more difficult by claiming all unused IPs).